# iPhone database

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Could you guys let me know which is better, using sqlite3 or core data? What are the pros and cons using either method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your use case?

Core Data is a pretty hefty framework and it offers a lot more than just plain old persistence. It incorporates support for faulting, relationship management of objects, schema migration support, validation and nice integration with UITableViews via the NSFetchedResultsController.  The big win for me is that it's completely modelled on objects.  Sqlite is more than adequate for an app with a single isolated table, high scores in a game etc, but for anything more complex I would consider core data.

Apple's introduction to Core Data mind help you decide if it's appropriate for you or not...

[Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTechnologyOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009296-SW1)

Comment: thanks..dude..mine is simple i m parsing an rss feed and storing it sqlite currently...will it anyway improve my preformance using core data

Comment: Again the answer depends on your use case here.  One of the features of Core Data is support for faulting (ability to cache persisted objects in memory) which may give you a reduction in memory usage.  If in your app you're doing more than parsing/storing i.e. querying a large set of previous feeds then it might be worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite3 is better to use for the database, because of using this sqlite3 you can access easily the data and It's easier as you do query on other database like SQL, ORACLE.

Comment: thanks dude..as far iphone is concerned i want to know which is better..sqlite or core data